# Implementing PowerSets in Java

Tags: java, powerset

```
import java.util.*;

public class BruteForce {
    static int numObject;
    static int weightThreshold = 0;
    static double numCombination;
    static BruteForce knapsack = new BruteForce();
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.print("Enter weight threshold: ");
        weightThreshold = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter number of objects: ");
        numObject = input.nextInt();

        String[] variables = new String[numObject];
        int[] weightObject = new int[numObject];
        int[] costObject = new int[numObject];
        Random rand = new Random();
        Random r = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < numObject; i++) {
            char temp = (char) (r.nextInt(26) + 'a');
            variables[i] = Character.toString(temp);
        }
        System.out.println("Variables Array: " + Arrays.toString(variables));
        for (int i = 0; i < numObject; i++) {
            int n = rand.nextInt(50) + 1;
            weightObject[i] = n;
        }
        System.out.println("Weights Array: " + Arrays.toString(weightObject));
        for (int i = 0; i < numObject; i++) {
            int n = rand.nextInt(100) + 25;
            costObject[i] = n;
        }
        System.out.println("Cost Array: " + Arrays.toString(costObject));

        knapsack.possibleCombinations(variables, weightObject, costObject, weightThreshold, numObject);
    }

    public void possibleCombinations(String variables[], int weightObject[], int costObject[], int weightThreshold,
            int numObject) {

        for (int i = 0; i < (1 << numObject); i++) {
            int weight = 0;
            int cost = 0;
            System.out.print("{ ");
            // Print current subset
            for (int j = 0; j < numObject; j++){

                if ((i & (1 << j)) > 0) {
                    weight += weightObject[j];
                    cost += costObject[j];
                    System.out.print(variables[j] + " ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("}");
            System.out.print("\t" + weight + "\t" + cost);
        }
    }

}
```

I'am trying to implement a PowerSet. I'am trying to solve the knapsack problem, using brute force. So I have to create all the subsets of the set and for each set add up the weights and values. Whichever weight that is under the `maxWeight` and has the highest value is chosen.

I'am only at the point of making all the sets. I can make all the variable subsets but I cannot properly add the weights and values of the subsets. Here is my output:

```
Enter weight threshold: 1
Enter number of objects: 3
Variables Array: [w, b, x]
Weights Array: [29, 42, 42]
Cost Array: [55, 96, 38]
{ }
    0   0{ w }
    29  55{ b }
    42  96{ w b }
    71  151{ x }
    42  38{ w x }
    71  93{ b x }
    84  134{ w b x }
    113 189
```

I don't know where my loop goes wrong. w has a value of zero (which is of course wrong) and then all the other variables don't have their corresponding values. What am I doing wrong? Also, I will admit I got the  PowerSet loop from a website, but I just don't know why the loop works for the variables, but doesn't addup the weights and values.

Comment: Seems like you are confused by the output formatting. You print the newline between the set and its values, hence `{ }` (empty set) belongs to (`0  0`) (no cost) and so on. Given that, the algorithm seems fine (albeit it only works for up to 31 items). Try to move the `println()` to the next output line and you should be fine.

Comment: Wow, of course. I don't know how I didn't notice that. Thank you for pointing that out.